# Is the determinant of a matrix some kind of "integral" of the linear mapping?

Tags: integration, matrices, vector-spaces

A $n \times n$ matrix corresponds to a linear mapping between two $n$-dim vector spaces.

The determinant of a matrix gives a scalar, just as the integral of an integrable function gives a scalar.

So I wonder if the determinant of a matrix can be seen as some kind of "integral" of the corresponding linear mapping?

Thanks.

Comment: The interpretation as a volume of a parallelopiped is probably what you want here.

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by "some kind of". In terms of linearity, the trace might be closer to "some kind of integral".

Comment: @Ian: can you write the volume explicitly as both an integral and a determinant?

Comment: @Tunococ: I accept any "kind of", because I don't know. Can you write a trace for matrix explictly as some integral?

Comment: @Tim A matrix has finitely many elements. What kind of integration are you thinking about? What exactly is the thing you're looking for?

Comment: @Tunococ: some kind of "integral", for example, of the corresponding linear mapping to the matrix?

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is the volume of the image of a unit cube under the corresponding linear transformation.

Comment: @DanielRust: thanks. can you write "the volume of the image of a unit cube under the corresponding linear transformation" as an "integral"?

Comment: @Tim I think you need to be more precise. Would you accept $\det(A) = \int_0^1 \det(A) dx$? (I guess not.)

Comment: @Tunococ: no, that means nothing particular to determinant. I think Daniel Rust might be on one of the right tracks.

Comment: How about $\det A=\int_{T_A([0,1]^n)}1\:dx_1\ldots dx_n$, where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix? There is a sign issue too which will depend on if $T_A$ preserves or changes orientation.

Comment: @DanielRust: thanks. can you write it more like an "integral" of the linear mapping $T_A$?

Comment: @Tim you can write it as an integral over a cube by making a change of basis, but then the determinant of the Jacobian of $T_A$ is just the determinant of $A$ so, as Tunococ says you'll just get $\det(A)=\int_{[0,1]^n}\det A\:dx_1\ldots dx_n$ which is obvious.

Comment: @Tunococ:  Can you write a trace for matrix explictly as some integral? –

Comment: Trace is a sum, any sum can be written as a certain integral with a suitably chosen measure.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: but as an "integral" of the linear mapping?

Comment: @Tim Again, I think you need to be more precise. Is there an example of something similar to what you might want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a good connection between determinants and integrals.

However, if you are looking for a "calculus" interpretation, probably the best one is in terms of derivatives. For any differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, where $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\big(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$$ (all $f_i$ scalar functions of $n$ variables), the function is locally approximated by a linear transformation $Df$, the matrix derivative of $f$. $$Df=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}\end{bmatrix}$$ As you note, all linear functions can be represented by a matrix, like the one above. The *determinant* of this matrix is then the *volume expansion factor* - that is, the amount by which small $n$-volumes are enlarged.

This shows up prominently in the [change of variables formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) for integrals, where one takes the determinant of the derivative matrix (called the Jacobian) as a "fudge-factor" so that any distortions caused by the transformation are corrected for.

Answer (score 1):

Theres not really any connection there. If you really want to stretch it you could integrate [Jacobi's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) I suppose.